# Is the entry procedure at Cairo airport the same as at Hurghada airport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, egypt

I'm soon flying from London to Cairo and wonder whether the entry procedure is similar to that at Hurghada airport (both are in Egypt)?

At Hurghada, I go to a National Bank of Egypt desk located before immigration and present my ID and a photo, whereby the photo and visa are affixed onto a yellow form. Then on to immigration, where I present the ID and visa form and get the latter stamped.

Are there any differences at Cairo airport - in particular, is it the National Bank of Egypt that sells the visa for the official price there as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visa procedures at Cairo International Airport are the same as Hurghada. You can use the bank counter to pay the visa fees as you have mentioned. If you will be on EgyptAir flight there will be a video demonstration prior to landing explaining the whole process. If you will arrive at Terminal 2 in case you will use BA, Terminal 2 has more clear signs which to make it easier to reach to the bank/visa counter.

Comment: Perfect! One more thing: I recently heard that several different banks issue visas at terminal 3 for the official price, is this true?

Comment: Yes, there are more than bank counter and all offer the official price, list of banks available at Cairo International Airport Terminal 3 could be found [here](http://www.cairo-airport.com/services_banking.asp) some of the banks available prior to immigration where you can get the visa, and some after customs where usually you can use for forex exchange. The most important thing is, don't queue without visa to avoid wasting time.